# Dificuldade em actualizar variável global. c

Tags: c, variáveis, variáveis-globais

Estou a desenvolver o seguinte código e estou a utilizar variáveis globais que podem ser alteradas em diferentes partes do código, mas quando altero por exemplo a variável state na função menu() o seu valor não é alterado nas outras funções que a utilizam, ou seja as variáveis são globais mas não são actualizadas.
Será por estar a fazer varios processos para correr todas as funções em simultâneo ou estou a fazer alguma coisa mal?

```
/* menu para acesso as funcionalidades */
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define sensoralarme    3
#define saidaalarme     9
#define saidaalarme2   26
#define sensoralarme2 11
#define botaoreset 31
#define saidaclimatizacao 12
#define botaoaumenta 0
#define botaodiminui 2
#define saidajanela1 27 
#define saidajanela2 23
#define abrirjanela 5
#define fecharjanela 4
#define ldr 29



void menu();
void iluminacacao();
void intrusao();
void janelas();
void toggle();
void disparo();
void reset();
void climatizacao();
void toggleclimatizacao();

//int disparo = (digitalRead(sensoralarme));
int estadoalarme;
int estadojanela;
int estadojanela2 = 3 ;
//int *ptr_int = &estadojanela2;
int rr;
 int bright=0 ;
 int state=0;
 int statedisparo=0;
int statedisparo2;
int toggleCount = 0;   // used to count number of falling edges received.
int estadoclimatizacao;
int estadoclimatizacao2;




int main()
{

    int i,r, n=5;
    wiringPiSetup ();
    pinMode (1, PWM_OUTPUT); /* pwm iluminação*/
    pinMode (0, INPUT);/*aumenta luminusidade*/
    pinMode (2, INPUT); /* diminui luminusidade*/
    pinMode (9, OUTPUT); /* saída disparo alarme*/
    pinMode (3, INPUT); /*sensor alarme*/
    pinMode (12, OUTPUT); /*saída climatização */
    pinMode (27, OUTPUT); /*saída janela abrir */
    pinMode (23, OUTPUT); /*saída janela fechar */
    pinMode (29, INPUT);/*ldr*/
    pinMode (5, INPUT); 
    pinMode (4, INPUT); 
    pinMode (6, INPUT);
    pinMode (25, OUTPUT);/*sensir janela aberta */ 
    pinMode (saidaalarme, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (saidaalarme2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (sensoralarme, INPUT);
    pinMode (sensoralarme2, INPUT);
    pinMode (botaoreset, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(saidaalarme2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(saidaalarme, LOW);
    digitalWrite(saidaalarme,0);
    digitalWrite(saidaclimatizacao,0);
    digitalWrite(saidajanela1,0);
    digitalWrite(saidajanela2,0);
    //pwmWrite (1, 0);
    printf("Bem Vindo.\n"); 
    printf("Pressione OK para continuar\n");
    getchar();
    r=fork();
    if(r==0)
    {
        printf(" \n.....A iniciar sistemas iluminacao\n \n ");
        iluminacao();
        exit(0);
    }
    r=fork();
    if(r==0)
    {
        printf(" \n.....A iniciar sistemas intrusao \n \n ");
        intrusao();
        exit(0);
    }
    r=fork();
    if(r==0)
    {
        printf(" \n.....A iniciar sistemas  climatizacao\n \n ");
        climatizacao();
        exit(0);
    }
    r=fork();
    if(r==0)
    {
        printf(" \n.....A iniciar sistemas janelas \n \n ");
        janelas();
        exit(0);
    }
    delay (500);
    system( "clear" );
    menu();

    /*for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {

        if(fork()) break;
    }

    if(i==n)
    {
        menu();

    }
    else
    {
        printf(" \n.....A iniciar sistemas \n \n ");
    }
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            iluminacao();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            intrusao();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            climatizacao();
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            janelas();
            break;
        }
    }*/

 /*int r;
 r=fork();
 if (r==0)
 {iluminacao();intrusao();climatizacao();janelas();}
 else
 {menu();}
    return 0;*/


}

void menu()
{
    int escolha1;
    int r;
    int estadoclimatizacao;
    int lum;
    int estadointrusao;


    //printf(" estado janela2:%d\n",  *ptr_int);
    printf("SISTEMAS \n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Escolha umas das seguintes opções:\n");
    printf("1. iluminação.\n");
    printf("2. Intrusão.\n");
    printf("3. Climatização.\n");
    printf("4. Janelas.\n");
    printf("0. Sair.\n");
    scanf("%d", &escolha1);
    switch ( escolha1 )
    {
        case 1:
        {
            printf("intruduza o nivel de luminusidade desejado de 0 a 10 \n");
            scanf("%d", &lum);
            bright=lum*102.4;
            printf("%d: lum\n",bright);
            pwmWrite (1, bright);
            menu();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            printf(" Para ligar prima 1\n Para desligar prima 0\n");
            scanf("%d", &estadointrusao);
            if (estadointrusao==1 && state ==0)
            {
                digitalWrite(saidaalarme, HIGH);
                state=1;
                menu();
                break;
            }
            else if (estadointrusao==1 && state ==1)
            {
                printf(" Sistema já se encontra ligado!\n");
                menu();
            }
            if (estadointrusao==0 && state == 1 && statedisparo == 0)
            {
                digitalWrite(saidaalarme, LOW);
                state=0;
                menu();
                break;
            }
            else if (estadointrusao==0 && state ==0)
            {
                printf(" Sistema já se encontra desligado!\n");
                menu();
            }
            else if (estadointrusao==0 && state ==1 && statedisparo == 0)
            {
                printf(" Sistema terá de ser desligado localmente!\n DISPARO\n");
                menu();
            }
        }
        case 3:
        {
            printf(" Para ligar prima 1\n Para desligar prima 0\n");
            scanf("%d", &estadoclimatizacao);
            if ( estadoclimatizacao == 1 )
            {
                digitalWrite(saidaclimatizacao,1);
                menu();
            }
            if ( estadoclimatizacao == 0 )
            {
                digitalWrite(saidaclimatizacao,0);
                menu();
            }
        }
        case 4:
        {
            printf(" Para abrir prima 1\n Para fechar prima 0\n Para verificar o estado prima 2\n");
            scanf("%d", &estadojanela);
            if (estadojanela ==2 && estadojanela2 ==1)
                {
                    printf("janela ABERTa \n");
                    menu();
                }
            if (estadojanela==2 && estadojanela2 == 0)
                {
                    printf("janela fechada \n");
                    menu();
                }
            if (estadojanela !=2 && rr==0)
            {




                    menu();
                    //sleep(600);



            }
            else 
            {
                printf("passar para processo ja aberto \n");
                menu();
            }
        }   

        case 0:
        {
            kill(0, SIGTERM);
            /*comando para matar todos os processos criados*/
            digitalWrite(saidaalarme2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(saidaalarme, LOW);
        digitalWrite(saidaalarme,0);
        digitalWrite(saidaclimatizacao,0);
        digitalWrite(saidajanela1,0);
        digitalWrite(saidajanela2,0);
        pwmWrite (1, 0);
            return (0);
            break;
        }
    }

}

void iluminacao()
{

  //int buttonmais = (digitalRead(0) );
  int buttonmenos = (digitalRead(2) );


  printf ("dimmer\n") ;

  if (wiringPiSetup () == -1)
    exit (1) ;


  pwmWrite (1, bright);


  while (1)
  {


      while (digitalRead(0) != LOW && digitalRead(2) == LOW && digitalRead(29) !=0)
      {

          if (bright  < 1024 && bright >= 0)
        {
        bright = bright+1;  
        pwmWrite (1, bright) ;
        delay (4) ;

        }
        }
    while ( digitalRead(2) != LOW && digitalRead(0) == LOW && digitalRead(29) !=0)
    {
        if (bright  <= 1024 && bright > 0)
        {
            bright = bright-1;
        pwmWrite (1, bright) ;
        delay (4) ;
        }
    }

    if (digitalRead(0) != LOW && digitalRead(2) != LOW)
      {
          bright = 0;
          pwmWrite (1, bright);
      }
}


}


void janelas()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if ( estadojanela == 1 && digitalRead(25)==0 )/*abre janela via linha de comandos*/
                {
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela1,1);
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela2,0);
                    delay(500);
                    estadojanela2 = 1;
                    estadojanela=3;
                    printf("ABERTO \n");
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela1,0);
                    digitalWrite(25,1);

                }
                if ( estadojanela == 0 && digitalRead(25)==1)/* fecha janela via linha de comandos*/
                {
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela1,0);
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela2,1);
                    delay(500);
                    estadojanela2=0;
                    estadojanela=3;
                    printf("Fechado \n");
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela2,0);
                    digitalWrite(25,0);

                }
                if ( estadojanela == 1  && (digitalRead(saidajanela1)==1)  )/*para abertura de janela*/
                {
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela1,0);
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela2,0);


                    printf("ABERTura parada \n");



                }
                if ( estadojanela == 0  && (digitalRead(saidajanela2)==1)  )/*para fecho da janela*/
                {
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela1,0);
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela2,0);


                    printf("fecho parada \n");



                }
                if ( digitalRead(5)!=0 && digitalRead(25)==0 )/*abre janela via linha de comandos*/
                {
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela1,1);
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela2,0);
                    delay(500);
                    estadojanela2 = 1;
                    estadojanela=3;
                    printf("ABERTO \n");
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela1,0);
                    digitalWrite(25,1);

                }
                if ( digitalRead(4)!=0 && digitalRead(25)==1)
                {
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela1,0);
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela2,1);
                    delay(500);
                    estadojanela2=0;
                    estadojanela=3;
                    printf("Fechado \n");
                    digitalWrite(saidajanela2,0);
                    digitalWrite(25,0);

                }
    }

}

void intrusao()
{
    if (wiringPiISR(sensoralarme,INT_EDGE_FALLING,&toggle) != 0)
    {
        printf("Registering ISR failed\n");
        return 2;
    }
    if (wiringPiISR(sensoralarme2,INT_EDGE_FALLING,&disparo) != 0)
    {
        printf("Registering ISR failed\n");
        return 2;
    }
    if (wiringPiISR(botaoreset,INT_EDGE_FALLING,&reset) != 0)
    {
        printf("Registering ISR failed\n");
        return 2;
    }
    if ( saidaalarme == 1 && sensoralarme2 == 1)
    {
        digitalWrite(saidaalarme2, HIGH);
        delay(10);
    }

    // wait for ever so the program doesn't terminate.
    while(1)
    {


        // Yield the thread so CPU doesn't run 100%
        delay(5000);
    }
}

void toggle()
{

    // NOTE: LED is connected to +3.3V and to the PIN.
    // So configuration is active low. 
    if(state==1 && statedisparo ==0)
    {
        // Set -ve lead of LED to ground.
        digitalWrite(saidaalarme,LOW);
        state = 0;
        printf("%d: ALARME OFF\n", toggleCount++);
    }


    else
    {
        // Set -ve lead of LED to +3.3V.
        digitalWrite(saidaalarme, HIGH);
        state = 1;
        printf("%d: ALARME ON\n", toggleCount++);
    }

}
void disparo()
{
    //statedisparo = 0;
    if(state==1 && statedisparo==0)
    {
        // Set -ve lead of LED to ground.
        digitalWrite(saidaalarme2,LOW);
        statedisparo = 1;
        statedisparo2 = 1;
       // printf("%d: disparo off\n", toggleCount++);

    /*  do
    {
            digitalWrite (LedPin2, HIGH) ; delay (300) ;
        digitalWrite (LedPin2, LOW) ; delay(300) ;
    }
    while (state==1);*/



        while(statedisparo2==1)
        {


            digitalWrite (saidaalarme2, HIGH) ; delay (300) ;
            digitalWrite (saidaalarme2, LOW) ; delay(300) ;


        }


    }
    else if(state==0 && /*ButtonPin2 ==1*/ statedisparo == 0)
    {
        // Set -ve lead of LED to +3.3V.
        digitalWrite(saidaalarme2, HIGH);
        //statedisparo = 1;
        printf("%d: ALARME OFF\n", toggleCount++);
        printf("%d: disparo ON\n", toggleCount++);
        digitalWrite (saidaalarme2, HIGH) ; delay (500) ;
        pwmWrite (1, 256);
        digitalWrite (saidaalarme2, LOW) ;


    }


}
void reset()
{
    if(state == 1)
    {
        // Set -ve lead of LED to +3.3V.
        digitalWrite(saidaalarme2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(saidaalarme, LOW);
        //statedisparo = 1;
        printf("%d: RESET\n", toggleCount++);
        state=0;
        statedisparo=0;
        statedisparo2=0;
        return;


    }
}   

void climatizacao()
{
    //int flag=0;
    printf("climatização\n");

    if (wiringPiISR(digitalRead(6),INT_EDGE_FALLING,&toggleclimatizacao) != 0)
    {
        printf("Registering ISR failed\n");
        return 2;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        //if (digitalRead(6)!=0 && estadoclimatizacao2==0 && flag==0)
        //{
            //digitalWrite(saidaclimatizacao,1);
            //flag=1;
        //  estadoclimatizacao2=1;
        //}
        //if (digitalRead(6)!=0 && estadoclimatizacao2==1 && flag ==1)
        //{
            //digitalWrite(saidaclimatizacao,0);
            //flag=0;
        //  estadoclimatizacao2=0;
        //}
         delay(5000);

    }
}

void toggleclimatizacao()
{

    if(estadoclimatizacao==1 && statedisparo ==0)
    {

        digitalWrite(saidaclimatizacao,LOW);
        estadoclimatizacao = 0;
        printf(" climatizacao OFF\n");
    }


    else
    {
        // Set -ve lead of LED to +3.3V.
        digitalWrite(saidaclimatizacao, HIGH);
        estadoclimatizacao = 1;
        printf("climatizacao ON\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Tem como postar o trecho de código que tem o problema? Fica difícil tentar ajudar quando tenho 17 telas de código para ler

Comment: Eu nem vou tentar ajudar por uma razão: este código tem tantos problemas que resolver isto não vai mudar nada. Me desculpe a sinceridade, mas só começando de novo, desta vez do jeito certo.

Comment: Acredito que o código tenha muitos problemas, mas para quem tem muito pouco conhecimento na área não é facil reconheccer certos problemas, e até seria melhor começar de novo da maneira correcta, mas seria necessário saber qual é a maneira correcta. Mas obrigado pela ajuda e pela opinião.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função fork duplica todos os dados em memória do processo pai, incluindo variáveis globais. Então se você altera uma variável num dos processos, a mudança não será refletida nos outros.

Você tem que usar algum mecanismo de compartilhamento de memória entre processos pra atingir esse objetivo, ou criar threads em vez de processos, que teriam acesso às variáveis globais do processo que as criou.

Link em inglês, se ajudar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274786/how-to-share-memory-between-process-fork

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, vou analisar o que me sugeriu, usei a função fork() porque não tenho grade conhecimento de programação e como precisava de todas as funções a funcionar em ciclo infinito foi a maneira que consegui arranjar para o fazer, nunca me virei para threads porque nunca trabalhei com threads e não sei como usar.

Comment: A sua sugestão resolveu o meu problema! Obrigado